# Hide button after succesfully ng-click event?

Tags: angularjs

I have event for deleting data  when user clicks X icon for deleting data, data are deleted succesfully and displays status
DELETED, remember the default status is UNDELETED, what I want is when status is DELETED the X icon for deleting data should be 
hidden but if its not deleted X icon should be visible.

here is what I have done so far

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <a ng-click =vm.deleteData() <i class="fa fa-times><i>
    <label ng-show="vm.isVisible"> {{dataStatus}}</label>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       vm.isVisible =false;
       $scope.deleteData = function()
        {
        if(vm.dataStatus !== "DELETED")
        {
        vm.isVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
        vm.isVisible = false
        }

        };
    });
    </script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

this hide X icon whether its deleted or undeleted what am doing wrong? can some one provide best way to archieve what I want? thanks, am new here though :D

Comment: The template references `vm.deleteData` but the JS references `$scope.deleteData`. Template does not match JS.

Comment: <a ng-click =vm.deleteData() <i class="fa fa-times><i> -> this line should give you compilation errors, ng-click should be annotated <a ng-click ="vm.deleteData()"

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `ng-show` or `ng-if` on your button, much like you are doing with your status. For example:

```
<a ng-click="vm.deleteData()" ng-if="vm.DataStatus !== 'DELETED'">
  <i class="fa fa-times"><i>
</a>
```

Comment: so this will hide   <i class="fa fa-times"><i> after event is successfully?

Comment: @JasmineMamaj It will hide the `<a>` tag (which contains the `<i>` tag) if the status is "DELETED". This assumes that your delete function will update the status to "DELETED" after deleting the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can show your X icon only on those row which is not deleted yet like this

```
<a ng-click="vm.deleteData()" ng-if="vm.DataStatus == 'UNDELETED'">
  <i class="fa fa-times"><i>
</a>
```